# Character Limit for Form Control Button Names

Tags: vba, excel, button

I am currently writing a suite of macros for project tracking.  One of these macros programmatically generates Form Control Buttons for each new item to be tracked.  In order to allow for the generated buttons to launch a form with the appropriate data, I've designed the buttons to be named with the minimum amount of data necessary to access the appropriate data.

The problem I've run into is that if the data passed to the name is too long, the code errors saying: `the specified value is out of range`.  I'm thinking that I will just have to come up with an alternative identifier to pass to the button, but in the mean time, I'm curious if there is a specific character limit for the Names of Form Controls and if there is any way to raise or change this limit?  If not, what specifically is the character limit?

I use the button's name to store identifying data since I need a later program to know which data to access using the `Application.Caller` when the button is pressed.  Is there an alternative to have a button point to a specific data set?

Comment: Interesting. For me it tops out at 32 characters with the run-time error 1004: "Unable to set the Name property of the Button class". The limit for the caption seems to be 255 but it just gets replaced with the default caption "Button i".

Comment: You can use the `.Tag`property to store data instead of the name of the control.

Comment: @VincentG what benefit comes from using `.Tag` instead?  Just editted my post to clarify that I use the name to store data since I need to be able to see which button was clicked in another sub using Application.Caller.  Could `.Tag` be accessed this way?

Comment: If the file is `.xls` try saving it as `.xlsm` or `.xlsb`

Comment: My bad, I was thinking button controls on a form, not form control buttons. Not even sure if those have a `Tag` property.

Comment: @Slai you really think that that is my problem.....?  I'd think that my reputation and score on vba tags would indicate enough understanding of excel for that to be my problem....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could mess about with the button, and use some properties, so have a class called clsCustomButton

```
Public WithEvents btnCustomButton As MSForms.CommandButton

Private strDataDetail1 As String
Private strDataDetail2 As String
Private strDataDetail3 As String

Public Property Let DATA_DETAIL1(value As String)
    strDataDetail1 = value
End Property
Public Property Let DATA_DETAIL2(value As String)
    strDataDetail2 = value
End Property
Public Property Let DATA_DETAIL3(value As String)
    strDataDetail3 = value
End Property

Public Function INITIALISE(btn As MSForms.CommandButton)
    Set btnCustomButton = btn
End Function

Private Sub btnCustomButton_Click()
    Module1.DATA = strDataDetail1 & "_" & strDataDetail2 & "_" & strDataDetail3
End Sub
```

Comment: So is the basic notion here that the button of this custom type will store the data as new properties?  How would I access that using Application.Caller (or some equivalent "blind" call from another sub)?

Comment: You wouldn't need it, as you could handle it in the custom click, but it still exists as a button, so presume it would still work.  You could on the `INITIALISE` set the function dependant on the name/caption/tag of the control passed `c`

Comment: Oh, so instead of having `.OnAction` send it to a seperate sub that handles the click, the custom click itself would handle the processing, and it would have access all of the necessary data for that specific button as stored?

Comment: Certainly, think of the class as a button, then anything else that you want to add to it that you don't have, so each button could do what ever based on `select case me.name` in the click

Comment: Very cool.  Admittedly, I have minimal experience with classes in VBA and adding this in would entail rewritting a lot of code, so I have instead used a workaround solution that keeps me from violating the character limit, but nonetheless marking this answer as accepted for the very thorough solution

Comment: Cool, use it next time :)  Sometimes, you just cant do what you need to do, so need to start messing at this level to do it.  Event sinking is pretty much what we are doing

Comment: Just a small note: that uses ActiveX buttons, not Form control buttons. So you'll need to store all instances of the class somewhere and you'll have to reinitialse that store every time you open the workbook or the buttons won't do anything. (you can't assign macros to ActiveX controls)